# Remove class when scrolling past x-px (from bottom)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery script which adds a class to an element when it scrolls past a point on the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var s = $("#sticker");
        var pos = s.position();                    
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (windowpos >= pos.top + 380) {
                s.addClass("stick");
            } else {
                s.removeClass("stick"); 
            }
        });
```

And this is the HTML part.

```
<div id="sticker">
    <div class="widget">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'widget-area-2' ); ?>
    </div>                              
    <h3>Uw voordelen</h3>
        <ul class="ClassName">
            <li><strong style="vertical-align:top; margin-bottom:0px">Something A</strong>
                <div class="submenu">Some text A</div>
            </li>
            <li><strong style="vertical-align:top; margin-bottom:0px">Something B</strong>
                <div class="submenu">Some text B</div>
            </li>
            <li><strong style="vertical-align:top; margin-bottom:0px">Something C</strong>
                <div class="submenu">Some text C</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Now what happens is that the div `#sticker` is higher than the footer element, when the class `.stick` is added. This results in the content sliding over the footer element, which I do not want.

So the sollution I'm thinking of is to `removeClass` on the `stick` class when you have scrolled down an x of pixels on the page. So I tried the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var s = $("#sticker");
        var pos = s.position();                    
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (windowpos >= pos.top + 380) {
                s.addClass("stick");
            } if (windowpos >= pos.top + 900) {
                s.removeClass("stick");
            } else {
                s.removeClass("stick"); 
            }
        });
```

But no go, then I found a simular question on this page, but that is not exacly what I'm looking for. But I added it into my code, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var s = $("#sticker");
        var pos = s.position();                    
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (windowpos >= pos.top + 380) {
                s.addClass("stick");
            } else if (windowpos >= pos.top + 900) {
                s.removeClass("stick");
            } else {
                s.removeClass("stick"); 
            }
        });
```

Both codes do not do what I want them to do. Could anyone help me with the correct code or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your HTML as well.

Comment: @PaulRedmond Added HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The If-conditions are in the wrong order. You should use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var s = $("#sticker");
    var pos = s.position();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top + 900) {
            s.removeClass("stick");
        } else if (windowpos >= pos.top + 380) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick");
        }
    });
});
```

or even better:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var s = $("#sticker");
    var pos = s.position();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top + 380 && windowpos < pos.top + 900) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The second code worked like a charm.. don't know why Paul's code didn't work. It looks the same in basic...

Comment: the difference is the right order of the if's. You first need to check for the greater value and than for the smaller one.
I'm glad that I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in your code.

Here's a quick demo showing it working now:

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/jrzdxJ?editors=1111

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var s = $("#sticker");
    var pos = s.position();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
         var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowpos >= pos.top + 380) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else if (windowpos >= pos.top + 900) {
            s.removeClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick");
        }    

    });
});
```

Comment: I used my own HTML by the way, I started it before you updated your question.

Comment: For me that doesn't work. When I use your code I get a syntax error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'[Learn More]`

Comment: Did you try it on Codepen? I don't get any console error there.

Answer (score 0):

### Here's easy code to show it properly:

```
      window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };
        function scrollFunction() {
          if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
            document.querySelector(".fixed-top").classList.add("headerFix");
          } else {
            document.querySelector(".fixed-top").classList.remove("headerFix");
          }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.